# RegEx for capturing and replacing a string with quotes

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to `str_replace` in a function.

#### Attempt

```
str_replace(array('(', ')', array('"', '\'')), array('\(', '\)', '["|\']'), 'hello("test")');
```

#### Desired output:

```
hello\(["|']test["|']\)
```

This would work, but not very useful:

```
str_replace(array('"', '\''), '["|\']', str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('\(', '\)'), 'hello("test")'));
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: do an array_merge and the magic is done?

Comment: I'm not clear what "array in array" means, but `echo str_replace('"', '["|\']', 'hello"test"');` produces your output though.

Comment: @ggorlen i need using with ( and ), users are writing data and i not know which one is written ", '. hello"test" not static. maybe it could be hello'test'

Comment: Please provide more input and output examples covering all of your expectations.

Comment: @ggorlen i update the question, please check again

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really help much. I'm looking for something like "here are some examples of the behavior I want: input: `foo1` output: `bar1`, input: `foo2` output: `bar2`, input: `foo3` output: `bar3`" with a clear explanation of the transformation you want to perform. Otherwise, we're left to guess at your intentions, which doesn't help you.

Comment: This is work but not useful `str_replace(array('"', '\''), '["|\']', str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('\(', '\)'), 'hello("test")'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we might want to capture `hello` and `test`, then assemble what we like to have using a `preg_replace`:

```
$re = '/(.*)\("(.+)"\)/m';
$str = 'hello("test")';
$subst = "$1\([\"|']$2[\"|'\"]\)";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
hello\(["|']test["|'"]\)
```

#### RegEx

[image]

#### RegEx

You can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/V7yyp0/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]